# Finding dspace-source directory for mvn package

Tags: dspace

I am working with DSpace, this es the information about the version:

```
     Dspace version:  6.3
  SCM revision:  ${buildNumber}
    SCM branch:  UNKNOWN_BRANCH
            OS:  Linux(amd64) version 5.13.0-25-generic
  Applications:
                JSPUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                XMLUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                OAI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                REST at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                XMLUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                REST at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                OAI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                JSPUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                XMLUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                REST at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                OAI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                JSPUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                XMLUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                REST at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                OAI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                JSPUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                XMLUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                REST at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                OAI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                JSPUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                XMLUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                REST at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                OAI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                JSPUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                XMLUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                REST at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                OAI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                JSPUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                XMLUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                REST at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                OAI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                JSPUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                XMLUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                REST at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                OAI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
                JSPUI at http://localhost:8080/xmlui
     Discovery:  enabled.
           JRE:  Private Build version 1.8.0_312
   Ant version:  Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on December 25 1969
 Maven version:  3.6.3
   DSpace home:  /dspace
```

I am working with discovery configurations right now, and there are some customizations in the search and browse preferences that I need to do. But as I saw in other questions, in order to do that, I have to do an mvn package and ant update.
The problem that I am having is that I'm not sure where is my dspace-source directory, since I did not do the installation and I'm a begginer. I would appreciate any help.
[Also, I attach an image of what my directory looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWnod.png)

Comment: The screenshot you attached is the installation directory. Please see [Overview of DSpace Directories](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC6x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-OverviewofDSpaceDirectories)

Comment: you were right, there was an installation error and the src directory wasn't available. I posted another question with the specific topic I needed to find the directory about. thank you very much